# View Join Two Tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join

I'm trying to create this view on postgresql and I'm gettting the below error:

Create a view named: FacultyCourses: Join the Faculties, Courses tables using the faculty_id and display the values for the following variables: faculty_id, name (Faculties), level (Faculties), course_id, description (Courses), level (Courses).

```
CREATE VIEW FacultyCourses AS
SELECT faculty_id, name, level, course_id, description,level
FROM faculties, courses;

SELECT * FROM FacultyCourses;
```

ERROR:
ERROR:  column reference "level" is ambiguous
LINE 2: SELECT faculty_id, name, level, course_id, description,level
^
SQL state: 42702
Character: 56

Thank you all.

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: I agree but sadly think we fight a loosing battle. At least as long as the Postgres (and Oracle) documentation concentrate almost exclusively only the list of tables syntax  and barely mention the **standard** join syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column `level` is ambiguous, because it exists in both tables: qualify it with the table it belongs to - along with all other column (this is a best practice).

Also, your query is obviously needing a join condition between the tables.

So:

```
create view facultycourses as
select faculty_id, f.name, f.level, c.course_id, c.description, c.level
from faculties f
inner join courses c using (facility_id);
```

The `using()` clause for joins unambiguously resolves the column name - so there is no nned to prefix it in the `select` clause.

Comment: Thank you. I'm getting a new error: 
ERROR:  column "faculty_id" specified in USING clause does not exist in right table
SQL state: 42703

Comment: @Nick_Nick: your question mentions that this column can be used to join the tables. If that’s not the case, then you need to figure out what columns should be used.